# How to access an element inside the <td> element of the table which is being looped?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a nested looped tables below and I want to access an element inside the `<td>` element which is a `<div>` element named `divrep` which is currently closed.

I want to access this `div` element when the input button named `Reply` is clicked so that I can open it. I have a JavaScript code below to open it but it will always open the first row.

How do I open it in an exact index of the row of the table based on the index where the clicked input button is located? So far, this what I have:

```html
function OpenReply() {
    var div = document.getElementById("divrep");
    div.style.display = "block";
}

<table id="mytable">     

    @foreach (var item in Model.Comments )
    {
        <tr >
            <td class="tdstyle" >
                <div >  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name) </div> 
                <p>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comment) </p>
                <p> <input type="button" id="Reply" name="Reply" value="Replie(s)" onclick ="return OpenReply()" /> </p>

                <div id="divrep" style="display:none>
                    <table>
                    @foreach (var item2 in Model.Replies.Where(r => r.idrep == item.Id))
                    {
                        <tr >
                            <td >
                                <div> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.namerep) </div> 
                                <p >@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item2.reply)  </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    } 
                    </table>           

                    @using (Html.BeginForm("PostComment", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
                    {
                        <div class="editor-field" style="display:none; margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px">
                            <input type="text" id="comidvalue" name="idrep" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Id)" />
                            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="idrep" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <input type="text" id="namerep" name="namerep" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="namerep" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        <br />
                        <textarea id="reply" name="reply" style="width:445px;height:100px;resize:none" ></textarea>
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="reply" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        <input type="submit" value="Post Reply" name="butname" />
                    }
                    <br />
                </div>
            </td>       
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have more than 1 element with the same id.

Comment: You have a missing `"` in your code, in here: `<div id="divrep" style="display:none>`

Comment: @timmack - generate your `div` ID **dynamical**  like - **<div id='divrep_'+item.id' style="display:none>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use same `id` for multiple elements in same html document. Use `class` instead of id as shown below

```
<input type="button" class="Reply" name="Reply" value="Replie(s)" onclick ="return OpenReply()" />

<div class="divrep" style="display:none>

.....
```

Use below jQuery to show `divrep` div onclick of button

```
$(function(){
  $('.Reply').click(function(){
     $(this).closest('p').next('.divrep').show();
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w0nnxw75/11/)**

Comment: @DavidG, yes it must be `next('.divrep')`. Thanks for pointing out ..corrected :)

Comment: Now it doesn't open anything. Nothing happens using your codes.

Comment: have you included jquery library in your html document? if not then put this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in `<head>`tag. You can check my demo link is working.

Comment: And did you change the `id` to `class`?

Comment: Yes I change both ids to class and when you click any of the button nothing appears anymore. Why?

Comment: Have you check your browser consoel? can you share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement, I will look into it.

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar in your fiddle demo it works because it doesn't have a foreach loop in.Mine has. Please check closely.Thanks

Comment: @timmack This code should work regardless of your foreach loop. You have missed something or haven't given us the right code in the question.

Comment: @timmack, you can get a viewsource of your generated html and create a jsfiddle, we can figure out problem. as DavidG said, it is not depending on for loop.

Comment: @timmack, one more thing you have missed closing `"` in `<div id="divrep" style="display:none>`, so please correct it and try

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar and @ DavidG Now it works I just missed the dot on the divrep as you first posted as $(this).closest('p').next('divrep').show(); so no more need a onclick event on button and the function just directly triggers. Thanks guys

Answer (score -1):

divrep is an Id which is present Inside a LOOP ..It means There will be many element with the same ID which is not correct.
You should use Class instead of Id
and use a function `document.getElementsByClassName` to access it

Comment: You are looping ID which is not correct.. You will get an array of Elements having same ID.Use Class instead

Comment: It doesn't really make any difference if id or class is used in this situation, it still doesn't work because the OP has an incorrect javascript function

Comment: You must demostrate your code using document.getElementsByClassName before I can vote for it. But atleast thanks to your response.